# Regarding search keyword url

Tags: php

Thanks in advance..,
I want to fetch ( know ) the search keyword URL
Example:
Suppose in google or bing,etc.. we are searching for a keyword.,
It displays results, my url is on the first place.,
If user clicked the url ., it will come to my website. So basically i want that search ( googled ) URL

Kindly help us

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the referrer url which you can get using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and parse the term out.

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    /* break the url down into its components */
    $params = parse_url($url);

    /* make sure its actually filled with something useful */
    if (array_key_exists("host", $params))
    {
        /* parse the query params for easy keyword retrieval */
        parse_str($params["query"], $query);

        /* by search engine */
        switch ($params["host"])
        {
            case "www.google.com":
                echo "Google Search Term: " . $query["q"];
                break;
            case "www.bing.com":
                echo "Bing Search Term: " . $query["q"];
                break;
            case "search.yahoo.com":
                echo "Yahoo Search Term: " . $query["p"];
                break;
            /* more search engines here .... */
        }
    }
?>
```

It should be noted that http_referer is not 100% reliable as the client (the browser) is not actually required to provide it in the request. Furthermore URLs coming from a secured URL (eg. encrypted.google.com) will also not provide it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `Referer` header.  If you have a link from a Google search query, it will look something like this:

```
http://www.google.es/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=query&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=ppvfTfy8F4axhAfX2unDCg
```

The q parameter will tell you the search term.

Bing has a very similar URL format...the query parameter is even named the same!

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q=query&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all&qs=n&sk=&sc=7-5
```

Comment: I want exactly to fetch the searched URL . and it wants to store in my database

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, however do know that it may be empty (e.g. proxy stripping it, Google SSL search, etc).

Inspecting `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will reveal the URL of the search engine's results page the user is coming from, you have to parse it to extract the keywords, how to do it depends on the search engine.

Comment: I want exactly to fetch the searched URL . and it wants to store in my database with the keyword searched..How to do this please

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HTTP_REFERER`:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
```

This may, however, be empty due to proxy, SSL or other issues.

Comment: I want exactly to fetch the searched URL . and it wants to store in my database with the keyword searched..How to do this please

Comment: You need to parse it, e.g. with `parse_url`. See Wiz answer.